# Detect the end of a result set in php/mysql

Tags: php, mysql

How do you detect the last record in a result set when using php and mysql. In ASP its EOF (End of File). Whats the php/mysql equivalent? I'd like to know the last record so i can draw a line after it or close a  tag or anything else.

Comment: What kind of result set? What DB wrapper do you use?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use [mysqli_num_rows](http://php.net/mysqli_num_rows) to see how many rows there are in the result set and keep a counter to know how many rows you've printed.

```
$total_rows = mysqli_num_rows($resultset);
$counter = 0;
while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($resultset)) {
  //do something with every row here

  //last row?
  if(++$counter == $total_rows) {
    echo '<hr>';
  }
}
```

Or you can just loop through the rows and print your line/tag/whatever right after the loop:

```
while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($resultset)) {
  //do something with every row
}
echo '<hr>';
```